# E-visa for Turkey using Advance Parole

Tags: visas, turkey, us-residents, e-visas

I am residing in US and have an advance parole document, but my visa has expired. The e-visa requirements for Turkey say that I need to either have a valid US visa or a residence permit. Can I use my EAD (Employment Authorization Document)/Advance Parole document to apply for the e-visa?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/169601/transit-visa-in-frankfurt-on-advance-parole There’s a link to Timatic in the answer, input your itinerary and travel documentation details and it will tell you what you need to know

Comment: That link was useful but it does not answer my question. Based on the requirements of e-visa for Turkey it looks like I need a valid US visa or a Residence permit. So I am assuming the answer to my question is no and I am changing my flights

Comment: If neither Timatic nor IATA https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ allow you to input an EAD as one of your travel documents, the conclusion must be that without a valid visa your EAD is not acceptable for the purpose you were looking for.

Comment: Yeah, there isn't any option to enter the EAD on Timatic. I have changed my reservations to not have a layover more than 24 hours, so that I don't have to furnish an e-visa. Thanks for the help @Traveller